# referencing matrix for DEM

Tags: matlab, mapping

I've read in [Tile E](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/DATATILES/elev/e10g.gz) from NOAA/NGDC-GLOBE DEM ([tileinfo](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/report/s11/s11C.html) & [metadata](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/report/s11/s11D.html)) following the steps at [this blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/24/continental-divide-1-intro/).

I have a slightly different goal which is to find the highest point due W, SW, and NW of specific coordinates. So after I got matrix `dem` of the area, I created a referencing matrix:

```
Rdem=makerefmat('RasterSize',[6000 10800],'Latlim',[0 50],'Lonlim',[-180 -90]);
```

When I use `ltln2val(dem,Rdem,40,-105)` I get a value of -500 which indicates ocean. This location is in Colorado. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Thanks
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`makerefmat` is assuming the dem matrix is beginning at the bottom instead of the top which is common for many mapping functions. But because the Tile was read in using a generic function (not from the mapping toolbox), it acts like a normal matrix. `makerefmat` has an option to switch the direction in which rows are indexed for georeferencing. The proper syntax for Rdem is:

```
Rdem=makerefmat('RasterSize',[6000 10800],'Latlim',[0 50],'Lonlim',[-180 -90],'ColumnsStartFrom','north');
```